# Questions about transcript and PhD admission

Tags: phd, application, transcript-of-records

I recently received an email from a school that I applied to . They told me to resend the transcript since they could not see the grades. The problem is that my transcripts are long and it is easy to get lost. For example, grade in year 1 is in page 1, grade in year 2 is in page 5, grade in year 3 is in page 7. I have explained this to them but for other schools should I anticipate this and send them an email for explanation in advance? Or should I wait until they ask me to do so?

I have another question. On my transcript, there are some pages that are irrelevant and do not give a lot of information. However, I still decided to keep the transcript as it is when submitting the application because the document that contains the transcript says "any alteration to this certificate renders it invalid". Furthermore I do not want to omit any information because it is dishonest according to me. Do you think it is a good choice? As a result of this, the adcom might have trouble understanding the transcript because it is too long and they do not have a lot of time in general.

Comment: (1) I think you were right to submit the whole transcript; a partial transcript can look suspicious even if it contains all the "real" information. (2)  I don't think the problem is that "they do not have a lot of time"; that seems unlikely to produce a request to explain "in detail". (3) I wouldn't send the explanation to other schools now. If I suspected this problem beforehand, I might have sent the explanation along with the transcript, but now I'd just wait until someone asks for it. (But, having written the explanation for one school, I'd keep it on my computer, ready to send.)

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear in the original post. They did not tell me to explain in detail. They told me to resend the transcript because they could not see the grade. The problem is that my transcript is really long and it is easy to get lost. For example, grade in year 1 is in page 1, grade in year 2 and 3 are in page 5, grade in year 4 are in year 7. Should I anticipate this and send an explanation to other schools as well?  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should provide your own *summary* in form of a list, where each entry gives reference to the original translated document page.
And to do so independently of what you have wrote in a CV or other parts of your application. I mean make the summary a kind of cover letter for the official document.